# How to align asp.net calendar in middle of the page

Tags: html, asp.net, calendar

I cannot figure out how to align the calendar in the middle of a page.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="190px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="350px">
    <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
    <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:Calendar>

    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `div` style to this:

```
<div style="width:X%; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Set X to be the same as the width attribute for your calendar.

You can also change your calendar's width attribute to be 100% instead of a pixel amount, and then set the width attribute of your `div` to 50%. You can then toy with those to get them to look any way you want.

Comment: No problem. I added a bit more info that might help you to achieve more exact results.